# Calling Variables from Another Class using .self

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class A(object):
  const1 = 100
  const2 = 200

class Example(object):

  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.const = A() 

  def add(self):
    return self.a + self.b + self.const.const2
```

My question is why is it written is this way: `self.const = A()`?. In other words, what are we trying to accomplish here?

Comment: We are creating an instance of `A` and making it an attribute of `self` (an instance of `Example`)

Comment: If I say "We are creating an instance of `A` and making it an attribute of the object that we want to create ", is that a correct statement?

Comment: @far.westerner Yes, that would be correct terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute `const` of class `Example` is assigned an instance of class `A`. Because the attribute is an instance of the class `A`, it has its respective attributes: `const1` and `const2`. Here, they are probably trying to show you that you can do such things with classes.

Comment: _"Here, they are probably trying to show you that you can do such things with classes."_ - That's true and a valid point. But IMHO looks to me their trying to show that Python allows you to have multiple unique name spaces, and nesting them together is possible.

Comment: @elena: We put the name of the attributes as the arguments of the `__init__` function of class `Example`. If `A()` or `const` becomes an attribute, then why don't we put that inside the parentheses of `__init__` function?

Comment: @far.westerner `__init__`takes as arguments things that could influence/modify the values of the attributes. The attribute `const` is just an instance of class `A` though. So you don't need to provide an argument to `__init__` in order to initialize it.

Comment: @elena: My apologies for being fastidious: shouldn't we say - `__init__` takes as arguments things that could influence/modify the values of the object that we want to create.

Comment: @far.westerner These two statements are both true. We pass some arguments to `__init__`  in order to influence object's attributes, i.e. to influence object's values (values == attributes).  Of course, depends on what you mean by values.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a variable inside an Example Class Object to be a A Class Object. It would allow you to reference things like:

```
self.const.const1
```

or if you make an Example Class Object you can do the following to get access to the variables inside of the A Class Object.

```
exam_obj = Example(1, 2)
exam_obj.const.const2
```